# How to create generic method to parse nested json?

Tags: scala, parsing, jerkson

I hit a route of my microservice. I have common API to talk to any microservice and using jerkson JSON library.

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json

case class ApiResult[T](
                         private val content: Option[String],
                         private val error: Option[Throwable]
                       ) {
  def getRaw: String = this.content.getOrElse("null")

  def get()(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
       Json.parse[T](this.content.get)
  }
  def either(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Either[Throwable, T] = error match {
    case None    => Right(get)
    case Some(e) => Left(e)
  }

}
```

Now I have a singleton which has the list of methods to hit routes of another service.

```
object PurchasesTrait extends ApiResource {

def getData(payload: String): ApiResult[ProductPurchaseResponse] = 
r[ProductPurchaseResponse](POST, Url.core + "reports/productspurchased", payload)

 }
}
```

I have two case class,

case class QualifyingProductSummary(upcCode: String, description: Option[String], purchase: Option[Double])
    case class ProductPurchaseResponse(qualifyingProducts:List[QualifyingProducts], count: Int)

```
purchaseTrait.getData(payload) will give me the ApiResult(json, Nnone)
```

**json:**

```
{"qualifyingProductSummary":[{"upcCode":"6410077902","description":"Mini-Wheats Original","purchase":15.2},{"upcCode":"6410044886","description":"Corn Pops","purchase":13.7},{"upcCode":"041570055830","description":"Unsweetened Vanilla Beverage ","purchase":13.5},{"upcCode":"626027087802","description":"Organic Almond Milk Original","purchase":12.5}],"totalQualifyingProducts":19}

val data = purchaseTrait.getData(payload).either
```

To get the data out of ApiResult when I use either on it,

It is not able to parse it in **ProductPurchaseResponse** because of **QualifyingProducts**. So how can I achieve it using the same library? 
I want the generic method to do the same for other nested JSON as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to convert an instance of `QualifyingProducts` to stringified json and call `purchaseTrait.getData` with it?

Comment: I have added json. Actually, I have to parse it in ProductPurchaseResponse but it is not able to do so because of inner object QualifyingProducts.